# Without making cache, how can we take images from assets catalogs in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimage

I have placed my images in assets catalogs and want those images but without cache?
Is there any method available in Objective-C?

Comment: Without cache ? Why? `UIImage` `imageNamed:` cache them.

Comment: Have you tried -initWithContentsOfFile: with image extension?

Comment: So many images are there , only one load is needed , cache cases to growing memory

Comment: "initWithContentsOfFile" is fine !!! But how can i use it with images , which are stored in assets catalog for slicing. Do you have any idea about the problem

Comment: You have to pick them one by one or one at a time.

Comment: it's an animation , 100 images are there , Need to load  an array  of images as a time for preparing for the animation

Comment: see this post for your problem solution *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856283/use-xcassets-without-imagenamed-to-prevent-memory-problems/23438145#23438145*

Comment: Worth full link for to the Answer : Anyone checked ? " After ios 8 came , the UIImage imageNamed: won't make problem , Even its taking image form catalog assets"