# In iOS/Swift, at runtime how do you actually get just the full path of an image in the project?

Tags: ios, swift, image, path

Say you use ...

```
let x = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")
```

UIImage "knows" how to find the image "example.jpg"

But say you are using, for example,

```
let y = CGDataProvider(filename: ...)
```

In fact, "example.jpg" won't work. You need the full path.

What is it that `UIImage#named` does to convert "example.jpg" to the full path; how can we do that?

Comment: There's actually a few existing questions that have asked this but none seem to have a proper answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856283/use-xcassets-without-imagenamed-to-prevent-memory-problems and look at several of the "Related" questions to it as well.

Comment: great stuff @HangarRash TY (and great nickname :) )