# How can I use UIImage(contentsOfFile:String) method to load images from Images.xcassets folder

Tags: swift, uiimage

I know the difference between `UIImage(named:String)` and `UIImage(contentsOfFile:String)`,and I just have over 200MB images saved into **Images.xcassets** folder. I found that there is a huge memory usage of my app(**over 500 MB**),so I consider using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:String)` constructor,because it does not cache image. And I googled a lot and found the following solution.

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("my_img_name",ofType:"png"))
```

Howerver, when it runs, the app crashed.
Here is the link that might relate to my question:[Access Asset Catalog pathForResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968352/access-asset-catalog-pathforresource)

Comment: Are you still referring to the iOS 2 bug that leaked memory when `imageNamed:` was used? That problem was fixed more than 5 years ago. It is safe to use `imageNamed:`. The images are removed from memory when they are not referenced and memory pressure increases. Are you testing on a real device? The iOS Simulator is not really memory constrained, so it does not clear the image cache.

Comment: This, and if I understand the assets concept you won't have separate image files to load as they are going to be "compiled" into a binary with a special structure, even if this is not the case at the current iOs version.

Comment: I have to apologize that I did pass a wrong image path to my constructor.Problem solved.