# Unable to get a URL from assets-library

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking, icloud

I want to send image to server for it i am displaying `PhotoLibrary` from `UIImagePickerController`

Whenever user selects any photo from ImagePicker i pick up url of image.

but it shows in the format of assets-library which i don't want (Output of my log) `localUrl =assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473&ext=JPG`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        NSLog(@"localUrl =%@",localUrl);

    }];

}
```

I want it to be in the format of `file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85CBED11-A318-4096-B52A-EBC3879F7B34/data/Containers/Data/Application/805BB62D-E32E-4D1E-99B6-C91103A1D99B/tmp/testing.doc`

How do i achieve this?

**Please help and thanks in advance!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Asset Catalog pathForResource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968352/access-asset-catalog-pathforresource)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need to do this case. but you can try it.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{    
       NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ivPickedImage.image);
       NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
       NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
      [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
       NSLog(@"localUrl =%@",filePath);
    }];
}
```