# How can I play a sound from the asset catalog using AVAudioPlayerNode?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudioplayernode, avaudiofile

I'm trying to use an `AVAudioPlayerNode` to play sounds from the `Assets.xcassets` asset catalog, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've been using `AVAudioPlayer`, which can be initialized with an `NSDataAsset` like this:

```
let sound = NSDataAsset(name: "beep")!
do {
    let player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: sound.data, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeWAVE)
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
} catch {
    print("Failed to create AVAudioPlayer")
}
```

I want to use an `AVAudioPlayerNode` instead (for pitch shifting and other reasons). I can create the engine and hook up the node OK:

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
func playSound(named name: String) {
    let mixer = engine.mainMixerNode
    let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    engine.attach(playerNode)
    engine.connect(playerNode, to: mixer, format: mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

    // play the file (this is what I don't know how to do)
}
```

It looks like the method to use for playing the file is `playerNode.scheduleFile()`. It takes an `AVAudioFile`, so I thought I'd try to make one. But the initializer for `AVAudioFile` wants a URL. As far as I can tell, assets in the asset catalog are not available by URL. I can get the data directly using `NSDataAsset`, but there doesn't seem to be any way to use it to populate an `AVAudioFile`.

Is it possible to play sounds from the asset catalog with an `AVAudioPlayerNode`? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

OK so your problem is that you would like to get a `URL` from a file in your Asset catalog right?

I've looked around but only found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748972/4063602)

As it says

> It basically just gets image from assets, saves its data to disk and return file URL

You should probably change it to look for MP3 files (or WAV or whatever you prefer, maybe that could be an input parameter)

So you could end up with something like:

```
enum SoundType: String {
    case mp3 = "mp3"
    case wav = "wav"
}

class AssetExtractor {

    static func createLocalUrl(forSoundNamed name: String, ofType type: SoundType = .mp3) -> URL? {

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let cacheDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let url = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).\(type)")

        guard fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path) else {
            guard
                let image = UIImage(named: name),
                let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            else { return nil }

            fileManager.createFile(atPath: url.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
            return url
        }
        return url
    }
}
```

Maybe a bit far fetched but I haven't found any other options.

Hope that helps you.